# WKWebView is not displaying Images

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, wkwebview

As the title says i am trying to open a webpage in `WKWebView` but when the page opens there are no images being displayed instead everywhere where there are supposed to be images, question marks are being displayed.

My Code

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    var webRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios")!)
    webView.load(webRequest)

}
```

As you can see there is not much in terms of code but i would be very grateful for any kind of help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get rid from question mark in a blue square in UIWebView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3907928/how-to-get-rid-from-question-mark-in-a-blue-square-in-uiwebview)